# What does this command do

Tags: unix, command, node-webkit

I have nw executable file...

```
sed -i 's/udev\.so\.0/udev.so.1/g' nw
```

the Node-webkit application binary.

I am running ubuntu 14.04Lts i tried to open nw with ./nw. i doesn't open.

After that i typed in the above command. It started working.

I am too curious to know what that command did to my executable.

I know sed is for matching file patters with regular expression. how can it operate on .exe (application/x-executable) file.

Please anyone explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sed command that you've used searches the nw executable file (like an ordinary text file imagine) for any occurrence of the string **udev.so.0** and substitutes it with **udev.so.1**. The backslashes **\.** before the dots are just for escaping the **.** character, which is a special character for sed (it means any character - a wildcard like ******* is on windows systems). The **g** character at the end of your command denotes also to continue searching a specific line, even if a first occurrence has been already found. This way the whole file - nw here - is being searched and replaced.

Comment: yes and .... the probability of file `nw` still being a working executable once this modification is complete is close to zero. `sed` is designed to process text files that terminate lines of text with the `\n` (newline) character and do NOT contain null chars. Good luck to all.

Comment: That is an executable not a text file. How does sed look for search? I mean is it possible to search text on exe file...?

Comment: If you run `strings nw` on a console you will see that even executable files do contain some strings. As Shelter commented, the above replacement is more or less a hacking approach. You cannot be assured that this will work. However, the sed command will do the replacement "successfully" IMO.